# why imagepicker says no videos

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

i have videos in my ipod but the imagepicker says there in no video if anybody could crack it ill appreciate it

```
UIImagePickerController *videopicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
videopicker.delegate = self;
videopicker.mediaTypes =
[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];
videopicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
[self presentModalViewController:videopicker animated:YES];
videopicker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
```

Comment: Have you been trying on the simulator?

Comment: yes but on the ipod its the same

Comment: is there any video in your photolibrary ?

Comment: yes there are a few ... ive been searching a but and i read this document on a site that uiimagepickercontroller doesnt support ipod tocuch and 3g ..it runs only on 3gs+ devices coz of h.64 processor thing ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code is working fine for me it showing both photo and video

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum]) {

            UIImagePickerController *apicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            apicker.delegate = self;
            apicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
            **apicker.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum];**
            [self presentModalViewController:apicker animated:YES];
        }
    }
```